# Is $K(x)/K$ transcendental extention?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field. **Is the extention $K(x)/K$ transcendental?**

My first thought went to: Let's take the extention $L/K$ and a transcedental  element $a\in L$ over $K$. Then we know that $K(\alpha) \cong K(x)$. But, then $[K(\alpha):K]=\infty$. So, $[K(x):K]=\infty$.

But I stuck in this point which I think that doesn't help.
Is this syllogism right?

PS: $K(x)$ is the field of rational functions with coefficients over $K
$.

*Thank you.*

Comment: First, what is $L$? Also, I'm not sure where your starting point is, but I feel like most (if not all) of the time, $x$ is defined to be a transcendental element over $K$ so that $K(x)/K$ is transcendental by definition.

Comment: I suppose that $L$ is the biggest field that contains $K$. Is this wrong?

Comment: I was mostly commenting that you never defined what $L$ was in your post. But in any case, there is no biggest field that contains $K$, so the concept doesn't really make any sense. If $L$ is any field containing $K$, then $L(x)$ is a strictly larger field, where $x$ is some transcendental element over $L$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that the element $x\in K(x)$ is transcendental.  If it were algebraic, that would mean there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\in K$ such that $$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0.$$  But by definition, a polynomial is only equal to zero if all of its coefficients are zero, and so this is impossible.  Thus $x$ is transcendental over $K$ and so $K(x)$ is a transcendental extension of $K$.

[There is some minor sleight-of-hand going on here, in that $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ should refer to the element of $K(x)$ obtained by evaluating that expression using the ring operations, rather than the formal polynomial with coefficients $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},1$.  But it is a basic result in the theory of polynomial rings that these are equal.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!